# How to peek into the data Internet Explorer saves for a web page

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

my pc suddenly went off while I was uploading some information. I rebooted afraid I was going to have to retype all the information on the page, however after I restored session, I was provided option to refresh the page which seemed to have the previous data, but after refreshing with the upload, I get the error:

> Forbidden (403)
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> More information is available with DEBUG=True.

I do not have any clue on how to solve this issue. However what I want to do now is to find a way to peek into the data IE is trying to use to refresh the page, surely it must be available somewhere.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
So far, I was able to locate

> %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery\Active

which seems to have certain data that might have what I am looking for but it contains strange data that looks like:

> ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ
>   þÿÿÿ
>   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿR
>   o o t   E n t r y
>   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                               g>4&&Í    7       K j j a
>   q f a j N 2 c 0 u z g v 1 l 4 q y 5 n f W e           8    ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
>   h      T r a v e l L o g
>     ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                       0       T L 0 
>    ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                       ¾
>   Does anyone know how I can interprete this kind of data? Thanks

Comment: That is an error generated by the server you are trying to connect to, some pages are secured and will not re-fresh. Refresh means to load that particular page again, which the website server won't allow, you will have to go back to the main page of that website and start over filling out the data.

Comment: @Moab: Yes, I've understood that, what I want to do now is to locate where the data is cached in internet explore data files and possibly read it, took me 2hrs plus typing all that and I'm not sure I can type something that good again.

Comment: As far as I know IE cache is in the "temporary internet files" folder for the logged on user, which is hidden in windows by default. Not everything is cached, especially on secure web pages.